# Are there any DDOS mitigation services that are free or at least cheap that can protect port 25565?

Tags: server, proxy, minecraft, firewall, cloudflare

I'm running a Minecraft server on one of my old computers. I'm planning on opening it to the public but I want to first secure everything. I bought a domain for the server and tried to use Cloudflare but apparently Cloudflare only protects ports 80 and 443 https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxQOw.png. I haven't been able to find a free or at least cheap proxy that could protect port 25565 which is the port that the server runs on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there are any free services for that. The closest is Cloudflare, but that's only for HTTP traffic like you said.

However, just quite recently they've released Spectrum, that allows you to proxy any TPC/UDP port, which means you can proxy your game server ports through it ([source](https://developers.cloudflare.com/spectrum/)). It's not cheap though. Spectrum is only available for paid plans, and it's [charged on usage basis](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041721872#5idV42wG0hXZ3XqhGhpAHC).

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Cloudflare product](https://www.cloudflare.com/products/cloudflare-spectrum/minecraft/) but I think there are also other cheaper alternatives you can find by Googling.